# JPAUpdateClause com Join

Tags: java, jpa, join, sql-update

Tenho as seguintes entidades:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(schema = "MYDB", name = "TB_TESTE")
public class Teste implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "CO_TIPO_TESTE")
    private TipoTeste tbTipoTeste;

    @Column(name = "ST_REGISTRO_ATIVO")
    private String stRegistro;

}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(schema = "MYDB", name = "TB_TIPO_TESTE")
public class TipoTeste implements Serializable {

     @Column(name = "TP_ARQUIVO")
     private String tpArquivo;

}
```

Preciso fazer um update na tabela Teste com base em um atributo de outra tabela. Esperava que o seguinte código gerasse um update com join.

`JPAUpdateClause update = new JPAUpdateClause(em, QTeste.teste);
 update.where(QTeste.teste.tbTipoTeste().tpArquivo.eq("X"));
 update.set(QTeste.teste.stRegistro, 'N');
 update.execute();`

Porém, foi gerado o seguinte SQL:

`update MYDB.TB_TESTE cross join  set ST_REGISTRO=? where TP_ARQUIVO=?`

O SQL gerado tem apenas uma das tabelas necessárias para fazer o Join, e quando executado dá o erro ORA-00971: palavra-chave SET não encontrada. Há como faze o join no update de outra maneira?

Comment: Olá! Não entendi muito bem a pergunta, você poderia explicar melhor? O que eu não entendi foi a parte "Preciso fazer um update na tabela Teste com base em um atributo de outra tabela", você quer copiar os atributos de todas as linhas de uma tabela para a outra, é isso?

Comment: Olá! A tabela Teste tem uma referência para a tabela TipoTeste. Em TipoTeste, tenho a coluna TpArquivo. Preciso setar, na tabela Teste, a coluna StRegistro para 'N' desde que o TpArquivo do Teste seja 'X'. Como TpArquivo está em TipoTeste, me referi a ele como "um atributo de outra tabela". Até consegui fazer a query, só que precisei usar uma subquery. Será que há como fazer isso só usando um join no update?